# What is the deeper difference between QG Omega equation and QG Height tendency equation?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, fluid-dynamics

The quasi-geostrophic $\omega$-Equation

[image]
is a diagnostic equation for $\omega$ (=dp/dt = vertical motion) in terms of geopotential. It is derived in a few steps by manipulating vorticity and temperature equation.

On the other hand, by a similar manipulation or the same two equations, we obtain the quasi-geostrophic height tendency equation for $\chi := \partial \Phi /\partial t $
[image]

Both equations have are related to "vertical motion" ($\omega, \chi$), are they telling more or less the same? I marvel at the amazing similarities and the subtle differences of the two terms on the right. What are the applications of both equations in particular - when to use the first, when the second?